# How to set charset of gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I use gradle for my android application.But when I build it,I got some error like"error:need';'".And I aslo get some strange words where I use unEnglish words.So I guess the reason of it maybe the charset.So how could I set charset=utf-8 of gradle?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set the `file.encoding` Java system property. A good way to do this is via the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much and I tried it in the way "tasks.withType(Compile) {  
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"  
} "

Comment: Yes, `Compile` is now named `JavaCompile`.